# Keep Accessibility Behaviour With `tabindex` (or similar) When Tabbing Through Elements

Tags: html, css, forms, accessibility, focus

I have a form with some `<button>` elements in that I'm trying to get to work with the tab key for accessibility reasons. Each button has to be wrapped in a wrapper item, namely `.item-wrapper`.

I've added `tabindex="0"` to the button elements and to a `.close`  `<div>` element that closes the component, and everything works as expected in Chromium based browsers.

However, in Safari when you tab through the form elements the focus is only applied to the `.close` element and then jumps outside of the form, and doesn't even get to the button elements. In Firefox the buttons tab as expected however the `.close` element doesn't take focus.

Is there no standard cross-browser behaviour for this in 2022 bearing in mind as humans we can also send rockets to Mars? And if not how do I have it so the when tabbing through the form, the focus goes from the `.close` through to each button in order as desired?

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/oNyzbJW

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  display: inline-block;
}

.close {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: lightblue;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.item-wrapper {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div tabindex="0" class="close">X</div>
  <div class="board-list">
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <button tabindex="0" class="item" name="board-name">ITEM NAME 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <button tabindex="0" class="item" name="board-name">ITEM NAME 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <button tabindex="0" class="item" name="board-name">ITEM NAME 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
      <button tabindex="0" class="item" name="board-name">ITEM NAME 4</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Use naturally focusable content. Have you tried removing the wrapping div containers on the buttons? And your close DIV make that a button element and try styling it to get the outcome you are looking for. You may need to add/remove CSS props/rules to test the functionality of TABBING, but first and foremost use natural focusing elements like buttons and inputs. [This article](https://www.tpgi.com/using-the-tabindex-attribute/) may be helpful to you.

Comment: @dalelandry if I make the `div` a `button` this then has submit properties though? Also I need the wrapper elements for certain javascript to work with the `.closest()` method in terms of animated 'success' functionality.

Comment: `tabindex="0"` won't do anything because buttons are tabbable by default anyway. I suspect (although can't say for sure) you're just running into the strange default behaviour of the Tab key on Safari for the first time, which can be changed. See [here](https://osxdaily.com/2011/08/14/enable-tab-key-navigation-safari/) for example

Comment: Re: _"if I make the div a button this then has submit properties though?"_ No. It's true that if you add `<button>` then you get something very similar to `<input type="submit">`, but if you get into the habit of always writing `<button type="button">` (and it's a good habit to get into), then your button element will just be a simple button. Your `<div tabindex="0" class="close">X</div>` absolutely should be: `<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="close">X</button>`

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine - oh my life - I never knew that about adding `type="button"`, to buttons to override the default submit behaviour. A great little tip, thanks

Comment: @paulo77 - I know - it changes everything, right? Now you can have actual, real buttons in your UI. :-D